# Refactoring: combining two methods

Tags: c#, refactoring

Previously I had one method called "Search". This method actually did two things: Searched/gave back the found articles AND it calculated some data of the resultset. I now created two methods: one for searching and giving back the articles. The other Searches AND calculates the data.

The first method that only performs the search:

```
private List<SummaryRootEntity> search(int contentId,SearchModel query, bool includeTypeGroupFilters = true)
{
    cleanQuery(query);

    var inactiveForDays = getinactiveForDays();

    var searchProfileGroups = _manager.GetSearchProfileGroupsForSite(query.PropertyType);
    setLocationOfInterest(query);
    var searchBounds = _manager.GetSearchBounds(query.StreetID, query.SublocalityID);

    var shopsList = getShops();

    searchmodelDto.shops = shopsList;
    var filteredArticles = _articleService.Search(
        contentId,
        query,
        searchBounds,
        searchProfileGroups,
        inactiveForDays,
        includeTypeGroupFilters);

    // apply ordering
    var result = filteredArticles.ApplyOrdering(query.ForSaleOrRent, query.OrderBy, query.OrderDescending).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

The Second one that searches and calculates stats:

```
private List<SummaryRootEntity> searchWithStats(
    int contentId,
    SearchModel query,
    out FacetStatisticsModel stats,
    bool includeTypeGroupFilters = true)
{
    cleanQuery(query);

    var inactiveForDays = getinactiveForDays();

    var searchProfileGroups = _manager.GetSearchProfileGroupsForSite(query.Type);
    setLocationOfInterest(query);
    var searchBounds = _manager.GetSearchBounds(query.StreetID, query.SublocalityID);

    var shopsList = getShops();

    query.shops = shopsList;
    var filteredArticles = _articleService.Search(
        contentId,
        query,
        searchBounds,
        searchProfileGroups,
        inactiveForDays,
        includeTypeGroupFilters);

    var displaySearchResultSummary = getDisplaySearchResult ?? true;
    var stats = _articleService.GetStatistics(
        Site.ContentRoot.Id,
        shopsList,
        inactiveForDays,
        displaySearchResultSummary,
        searchProfileGroups,
        filteredArticles,
        query,
        searchBounds,
        Site.DefaultCultureInfo);

    // apply ordering
    var result = filteredArticles.ApplyOrdering(query.ForSaleOrRent, query.OrderBy, query.OrderDescending).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

The beginning of the second method is the same as the first one. The second method returns stats trough the "out"parameter.

Is there any way to get the calculation of stats in a different method? I could just rip the search out of the second method, but then I would have to define all the variables twice (inactiveForDays, searchProfileGroups, searchBounds).

Comment: Your second function never fills in the out parameter, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Dictionry<string, object> PrepareQueryValues(SearchModel query)
{
     cleanQuery(query);

     Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

     dic.Add("InactiveForDay", getinactiveForDays());
     dic.Add("SearchProfileGroups",_manager.GetSearchProfileGroupsForSite(query.PropertyType)); 
     dic.Add("SearchProfileGroups", setLocationOfInterest(query));
     dic.Add("SearchBounds", _manager.GetSearchBounds(query.StreetID, query.SublocalityID));
     dic.Add("ShopsList", getShops());

     return dic;         
}
```

So your first method:

```
private List<SummaryRootEntity> search(int contentId,SearchModel query, bool includeTypeGroupFilters = true)
{
      Dictionary<string, object> dic = PrepareQueryValues(query);

      searchmodelDto.shops = (CastToProperType)dic["ShopsList"];
      var filteredArticles = _articleService.Search(
      contentId,
      query,
      (CastToProperType)dic["SearchBounds"],
      (CastToProperType)dic["SearchProfileGroups"],
      (CastToProperType)dic["InactiveForDays"],
      includeTypeGroupFilters);

      // apply ordering
      var result = filteredArticles.ApplyOrdering(query.ForSaleOrRent, query.OrderBy, query.OrderDescending).ToList();

      return result;

}
```

Something like this should help, but I think this is overkill.

Comment: If you go the "data transfer object" way anyway, it's a lot cleaner to just make an actual class for that instead of using a dictionary with hardcoded strings.

Comment: @Nyerguds I agree with you on 100%.

Comment: Not super familiair with refactoring in .NET. Is this clean solution clean if i use the Classes instead of the dictionaries?

Comment: Best way to implement this particular solution is just to make a new class, something like "ResultPrefetchInfo", make all the variables you had in your function in there as properties, and then make a function to fill those in exactly as this answer does with the dictionary. It also has the advantage that the types of these properties can be different without needing any casting.

Comment: You can filled in the Constructor too if you want, the approach is like @Nyerguds explained.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the return value of the search as the argument to the stats:

So the signatures will be as follows:

```
private List<SummaryRootEntity> search(
    int contentId,
    SearchModel query, 
    bool includeTypeGroupFilters = true)
{
}
```

and

```
private FacetStatisticsModel searchWithStats(
    List<SummaryRootEntity> searchResults)
{
}
```

The you can call

```
var searchResult = Search(x, y, z);
```

Or

```
var searchResult = Search(x, y, z);
var statsResult = Stats(searchResult);
```

Comment: i also thought that, but that would mean that both methods would contain the first ~7 lines. Which would be duplicate code. so the variables (inactiveForDays, searchProfileGroups, searchBounds) would be declared in Search() and in Stats().

Answer (score 0):

Both functions do the same thing, only one of them does a little extra, right?

I'd just make them both into one funtion, and add an extra parameter `Boolean withStats` to the function arguments. Then you can just use if/else inside the function to execute the steps needed for each case. You have no duplicate code like that, just all cases in one function with partial branched functionality.

You'll get the actual full function, with all its arguments, as:

```
private List<SummaryRootEntity> search(
    Int32 contentId,
    SearchModel query,
    Boolean withStats,
    out FacetStatisticsModel stats,
    Boolean includeTypeGroupFilters = true)
{
    // I'll leave the actual combining part here up to you.
    // Shouldn't be too hard to implement.
}
```

Now, this is a bit clunky, with both the out parameter and the boolean; your normal search calls would need to define an 'out' parameter they never actually use, and both will need to give that boolean that can technically be inferred from whether you want to give or not give that 'out' parameter. You'll probably prefer to have the calls be as they were before.

Well, that's easy; just make two overloads that point to that same central function you just made. That takes care of these parameters for you.

Overload to call for search with stats:

```
private List<SummaryRootEntity> search(
    Int32 contentId,
    SearchModel query,
    out FacetStatisticsModel stats,
    Boolean includeTypeGroupFilters = true)
{
    return search(contentId, query, true, out stats, includeTypeGroupFilters);
}
```

Overload to call for search without stats, which makes and completely discards a dummy 'out' parameter:

```
private List<SummaryRootEntity> search(
    Int32 contentId,
    SearchModel query,
    Boolean includeTypeGroupFilters = true)
{
    FacetStatisticsModel stats;
    return search(contentId, query, false, out stats, includeTypeGroupFilters);
}
```

And boom, code compacted to one function. You will of course have to make sure that the "withStats=false" execution fills in the out parameter with null.